# Synonym for to-be-discovered?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What is an academic synonym for "to-be-discovered" in "The issue can be examined through a variety of discovered and to-be-discovered methods"?

The point for using to-be-discovered here is that I wish to emphasize that in future there may methods that can examine better the issue even if current methods can not do so fully. So, the issue still deserves discussion.

Comment: But how _can_ you say beforehand that these _to-be-discovered_ methods **can** be used to examine the issues? It runs into ludicrousness despite being grammatically ok.

Comment: I think you must say 'a variety of methods' and then say in a new sentence that other methods may be discovered in future.

Comment: I think that what you *want* to say makes sense. Methods exist, and the future may bring more methods that are better in some way that the methods already in hand. The problem here is your *construction*, where you force yourself into a “type A” versus “type B”  something, and English doesn’t have exactly the right words to convey the meaning you want. That said, there are other pairings you could use, such as **current** and **emerging**.

Comment: "Nascent" comes close.

Comment: @HotLicks very close, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said in the comment, specifically @Global Charm, all you can do is hold out the possibility that other solutions might emerge. The best you can do is say something like this:

*The issue can be examined through a variety of discovered methods; perhaps other methods, yet-to-be-discovered, may provide other insights.*

Insofar as you mentioned above, I would suggest it's more grammatically accurate to use hyphens thus: "The other yet-to-be-discovered methods . . ."

Comment: If you're going to go that route, why not just, *yet undiscovered*?

Comment: "Yet undiscovered" means "still undiscovered" with no implication that it will be discovered soon, but "Yet to be discovered" suggests it is likely to be discovered in the future.